# How can I distribute a standalone packaged Rails/Node/etc Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, windows, macos

I'm researching a situation in need of a remote site server. The site changes often. It usually has very limited internet connectivity, but a solid intranet that is utilized heavily. We need to serve clients at these sites.

Are there any modern tools available to package a traditional server stack that can be launched with a double click?

We greatly prefer development on macOS, but will also need to target Windows 10.

Comment: Traveling Ruby seems somewhat viable, but possibly stale. Maybe spin up an Thin server using `Thin::Server.start(...)` passing the Rails application as an argument. Traveling Ruby mentions a caveat regarding native extensions on Windows, though, and it's unclear if Thin would be available.

Comment: What kind of content you need to serve from the site?

Comment: Mostly tabular data, presenting as JSON in and out over websockets.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I know of (but have *not* tried myself) is a Go executable with embedded assets (with a tool like [Packr](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr)).